# Material-ui : darkTheme does not affect wrapped children

Tags: reactjs, themes, components, material-ui

My question is very simple, I want to use the Material-ui default darkTheme in a part of my app. Here is a sample of code :

```
<div>
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
    <div>
      <AppBar title="I am dark" />
      <MyCustomComponent label="I should be dark but I am not" />
    </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>
      <p>I am in the lightBaseTheme (default theme)</p>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
</div>
```

The first part of the app must be in the dark theme (that's a left menu), the second part in the light theme (that's the app itself).

The `AppBar` that is a direct child of the `MuiThemeProvider` is indeed dark, however, `MyCustomComponent` and its children (even when they are base Material-ui components such as RaisedButton) are not using the dark theme.

What is the simplest way to have `MyCustomComponents` and all its sub-children to use the dark theme too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap all inside `MuiThemeProvider` into one element.

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
  <div>
    <AppBar title="I am dark" />
    <MyCustomComponent label="I should be dark but I am not" />
  </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

actually you had to have an error like

```
MuiThemeProvider.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Of course only `Material-UI` components inside your `MyCustomComponent` will have themed appearance. Everything else you need to make manually: in a way shown by Jeff McCloud or by using context like this:

```
function MyCustomComponent (props, context) {
    const { palette } = context.muiTheme;
    // Now you have access to theme settings. for example: palette.canvasColor
}

MyCustomComponent.contextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

One more way to stylize plain HTML or React Components is to wrap them into 
[react-theme-provider](https://github.com/sm-react/react-theme-provider). Like this:

```
import ThemeProvider from 'react-theme-provider';

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
  <div>
    <AppBar title="I am dark" />
    <ThemeProvider>
      <MyCustomComponent label="I should be dark and I am!" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

reference: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js#L7

Comment: Hi, in my actual code I indeed put my components into a single `div`, I edited the question. The point is that the `Material-UI` inside `MyCustomComponent` are not themed, though they indeed should. Maybe I made some mistake, could you provide me a very simple example where it works for you ?

Comment: Okay I think I understand, the Material-UI are indeed themed, however they provide no default background color. Here my dark themed `MenuItem` appears white on white, and I thought those were styling issue.

Comment: Yeap, sometime you need to setup your own elements (like `div`s color/background-color) like shown in the answer. if you still have issues better to check your code or you can use [this tool](https://github.com/sm-react/storybook-addon-material-ui) to quick test different themes.

Comment: I added the react-theme-provider example to my answer as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to designate that your custom component is "themeable". You do this by wrapping your component in the 'muiThemeable' Higher-Order Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import muiThemeable from 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable';

class MyCustomComponent extends React.Component {
// ... your component will now have access to "this.props.muiTheme"
}


export default muiThemeable()(MyCustomComponent);
```

reference: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

Comment: Hi, I understand your answer, however what am I supposed to do with "this.props.muiTheme" inside my component ? To wrap its own Material-ui children with a `<MuiThemeProvider>` ?
The issue is not with my custom components, I understand that thay can't be automatically styled, however the Material-UI grand-children are not themed either.

Comment: Presumably, you're creating an HTML 'widget' of some kind inside your MyCustomComponent?  Let's say that widget has a couple DIVs, SPANs and a button - AND you want those to match the overall material-ui look and feel... You can use properties on muiTheme to match the colors, padding, border styles, etc... you can use values like "this.props.muiTheme.palette.accent1Color" or "this.props.muiTheme.appBar.height" or "this.props.muiTheme.spacing.iconSize" in the style(s) of your DIVs, SPANs, etc that make up your component. Hope that helps!